# Bijection from [0,1] to [0,1] sum [2,3].

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$0.0a_{2}a_{3}\ldots \rightarrow 0.a_{2}a_{3}\ldots$

$0.1a_{2}a_{3}\ldots \rightarrow 10.a_{2}a_{3}\ldots$

Numbers are base 2. Is this a valid bijection?

Comment: How are both 1 and 2 hit?

Answer (score 6):

Working with base representations is always tricky, since some numbers have multiple representations. E.g. - and working in base $2$ - we have $0.011111...=0.100000...$, but your definition would send the former to $0.111111...=1$ and the latter to $10.00000...=10$. So your "function" is not in fact well-defined.

Indeed, nothing quite as nice as what you're describing can *possibly* work, since there is no *continuous* bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$. So any bijection will have to be a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is equivalent to $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
2x& x\in [0,1/2]\\
1+2x & x \in [1/2,1]
\end{cases}$$

Notice this is not well defined when $x=1/2$